# How to get the value of the property "running" of AVCaptureSession?

Tags: objective-c, macos, avcapturesession

Following the documentation of AVCaptureSession (https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureSession_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/AVCaptureSession/running), there is the property "running"? How to output its value? Any piece of code is welcome since I am looking for the example of the code for Mac OS X.

Comment: an useful source: http://www.appcoda.com/understanding-key-value-observing-coding/

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found the way:

```
AVCaptureSession *captureSession = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init]; 
... 
NSLog(@"Its value is: %@", (captureSession.running) ? @"YES" : @"NO");
```